# Authentication with Mobile Services SDK for Android

Tags: android, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to make authentication to Google Provider using Mobile Services SDK for Android with my test Android app. I set client id and client secret of Google Settings in identity tab in my mobile service in Windows Azure, but i have strange problem. When I invoke login method than pops webview as white rectangle as in attached image instead webview with login page to google on emulator and phone. I make my authentication according to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbsIihGj6Dk

screen of white rectangle:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxcm9.jpg

My simple code to create login

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
try {           
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient( "https://mobileand.azure-mobile.net/", 
                "key", this );          
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, new UserAuthenticationCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(MobileServiceUser user, Exception exc,
                ServiceFilterResponse filter)           
        {
            if(exc == null)
                Log.d("google","login work");
            else
                Log.d("google","login not work");                   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 https://<website>.azure-mobile.net/
```

I don't know if you modified this line before pasting your code snippet,
but this URL is not valid.

Comment: The "<website>" - part has a format which is not allowed within https - urls.

Comment: I know, this was only replacement for my code snippet. "key" is also replacement for original key that i receive when i create my mobile service.

Comment: So without further investigations on logcat I can't give you a hint.

Comment: Ok, i find solution to my problem. Problem was associated with setting of ip address used proxy that i use to capture network traffic to further functionality of my app. Dynamic allocation of ip addresses change proxy's ip address, just now i notice that, so i change in settings to valid ip adress and now is working. Silly error.

Comment: Yes, but hard to detect.